# Click Handler in HTML inside FC event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using EventContent RenderHook to insert HTML in an event. And I am trying to attach a jquery click handler to it. Despite that the handler fires - the handler related with eventClick also fires, I do not want that since the mouse pointer points to the element inserted with eventContent.
It seems that bubbling takes place - i am not sure though.

Here is the code I tried

```
 eventContent: function(arg) {
      var startDt = new Date(arg.event.startStr);
      var endDt = new Date(arg.event.endStr);
      var start = startDt.getHours() + ':' + startDt.getMinutes();
      var end = endDt.getHours() + ':' + endDt.getMinutes();
      
      if(arg.event.extendedProps.stack == true){
        return { html: '<p>'+ start +':' + end +'</p><p>' +arg.event.title +'</p>' +'<span  data-      stackid ="'+ arg.event.id +'" class="stckNum" >+'+
 arg.event.extendedProps.stacknumber +'</span>'
      }
      }
    },
```

Here is the Jquery Handler:

```
 $(document).on('click','.stckNum',function(e){
     
     var stackedID = $(this).data('stackid');
     console.log(stackedID);

    })
```

stackedID is pritend in the console but also eventClick callback. fires as stated.
Here is the how the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="fc-event-main">
<p>9:30:11:0</p><p>Papageorgiou</p>
<span data-stackid="55" class="stckNum">+1</span></div>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the jquery handler on your whole document instead of only assigning it to your DOM element which is `.stckNum`. Instead of `$(document).on('click','.stckNum',function(e){` => `$('.stckNum').on("click", function(e){`

Comment: because the elements are dynamically created...and the handler you propose has no effect either way

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution after all. The eventclick callback has as argument an event object...this object contains jsEvent low - level information. By looking through the DOM properties **I can see exactly to which element the user clicked** and based on that **within eventClick callback** I can act accordingly.

The code is like this:

```
 eventClick: function (info) {
     
      //look through low level info to find exactly where the user clicked and if that is the stack number send and ajax request to bring the hidden events
   
       console.log(info.jsEvent);
       if(info.jsEvent.target.className == 'stckNum'){//icon clicked within event div...make and ajax request to bring hidden events
       }else{
//proceed with normal eventClick
       }
```